# Reasoning behind calculating the number of sub-arrays with odd sum

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com):

> Given an array of integers arr. Return the number of sub-arrays with odd sum.  As the answer may grow large, the answer must be computed modulo 10^9 + 7. 
> For `arr` = `[1,3,5]`, the output is `4`.

One of the [highly upvoted solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-sub-arrays-with-odd-sum/discuss/754706/C%2B%2BJava-O(n)) is like this:

```cpp
int numOfSubarrays(vector<int>& arr) {
    int odd = 0, even = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int n : arr) {
        if (n % 2) {
            swap(odd, even);
            ++odd;
        }
        else
            ++even;
        sum = (sum + odd) % 1000000007;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The author says, if we know the number of even and odd subarrays that end at the previous element, we can figure out how many even and odd subarrays we have for element n:

a. If n is even, we increase the number of even subarrays; the number of odd subarrays does not change. 
b. If n is odd, the number of odd subarrays is the previous number of even subarrays + 1. The number of even subarrays is the previous number of odd subarrays.

I 'understand' the 'workflow', but not the logic or the intuition behind it.  Specifically, I have the following questions:

a. What is an intuitive explanation of the steps mentioned by the author above? 
b. How does it guarantee that all the sub-arrays have been accounted for?  For e.g., in the above example, how is sub-array `[3,5]` account for, in the logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need to understand some basic properties of parity. If `a` is even, then the parity of `a + b` is the same as the parity of `b`. If `a` is odd, then the parity of `a + b` is the opposite of the parity of `b`.

In the code that you've posted, `odd` is the number of subarrays ending at the current element which have odd sums. `even` is the number of subarrays ending at the current element which have even sums. `sum` is the number of subarrays ending at or before the current element which have odd sums.

If the current element is even, then appending this element to any subarray preserves its sum parity. Therefore, the number of subarrays ending at the current element with an even sum is the same as the number of subarrays ending at a previous element with an even sum plus one, because every subarray ending at the current position is either a subarray ending at the previous position with the current element appended, or is a subarray of length one containing the current element. The number of subarrays ending at the current element with an odd sum is the same as the number of subarrays ending at the previous element with an odd sum, because every subarray ending at the current position with an odd sum is the same as a subarray ending at the previous element with the current element appended. We don't have to count the subarray of length one containing the current element here because that has an even sum.

If the current element is odd, then adding it to any subarray flips its parity. Therefore, we swap `odd` and `even` and increment `even` to count the subarray of length one containing the current element.

At every step we add the number of subarrays ending at the current position with an odd sum to `sum`, so at the end `sum` will contain the number of subarrays with odd sum ending at any position.

Comment: "...subarrays of odd length ending..." - could you please elaborate?  Why _odd length_?

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela Sorry, I meant subarrays with odd sum.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you! :)